# Dojo Drag and Drop does not work on specifically Windows 10 IE11

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dojo, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

The software(developed in dojo) I am working on has the feature of drag and drop, things were working fine on all the browsers, just recently our QA team informed me that the drag and drop feature of out product is not working on Windows 10 IE11 only, all the other browsers even including IE11 on windows 7 and 8 support drag and drop feature in our product.

I suppose this could be due to an update that got applied to the Windows 10 installation, since the QA mentioned that this feature was working on Windows 10 IE11 a few months back.

So I tried the following example on both the browsers and noticed that it failed on Windows 10 IE11 only
http://sitepen.github.io/sp-dnd-demo/4-dnd.html

Currently I am trying to debug the dojo code for Manager.js and Source.js
Till now I noticed that in Source.js the drag event is getting executed correctly but the target is getting cleared hence the onDrop event is not getting called

The dojo used is latest 1.10

Please provide me any pointers on resolving this issue

Thanks

Comment: On going through the code I noticed that whenever I brought the item to be dropped inside target area, the mouseout event was getting called on the Target. So when I commented the following line, It started working 

on(this.node, touch.out,  lang.hitch(this, "onMouseOut")),
Line Number 86 - Dojo\dnd\Container.js

Can anyone please help me understand this behavior in Windows 10 IE11

Comment: I tried the following solution
When the mouseout event was getting called I took the currentTarget property from the event attributed passed as the argument and compared the mouse pointer position (event.pageX, event.pageY) with the left/right offset and height and width of the currentTarget HTML Dom element. If the pointer was outside the currentTarget HTML Dom then the mouseout event is legit, else return without doing anything

Can anyone plases tell me if there is a better solution ?

Comment: I noticed this happens only on touch based laptops.